# Правильно ли расставлены запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Полученные таким образом результаты очень важны для разработчиков, но крайне дороги, и, к тому же, они имеют ограниченное применение в силу конечного числа экспериментальных моделей и условий проведения эксперимента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильно: "Полученные таким образом результаты очень важны для разработчиков, но крайне дороги, и к тому же они имеют ограниченное применение в силу конечного числа экспериментальных моделей и условий проведения эксперимента".

В данном предложении  соединительный союз И дополнен структурным элементом  "к тому же" с присоединительным значением.